# Update and nested select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to update prices of those products thats not been purchased by 1 year. How do I do that?

My current query is:

```
UPDATE product 
   SET price = price * 0.9 
 WHERE date_purchase > SYSDATE - 365 
   AND pid IN ([How do i select the items thats not been purchased in 1year??]);
```

I have 2 tables:

- Product => pid, p_name, etc... (pid = product id, p_name = product name)
- Purchase => pid, date_purchase, etc

Comment: do we have any other tables? Is this homework?

Comment: @rene: 2 tables: Product and Purchase. No, its not a homework. I put more details on 2 tables in my edited questions

Comment: Note: 1 year is not equal to 365 days. To get a year ago you can use `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a NOT EXISTS as it makes the requirement more transparent.

```
update product 
set price = price * 0.9 
where not exists
  (select 1 from PURCHASE pchase
  WHERE pchase.pid = PRODUCT.pid
  and pchase.date_purchase > add_months(sysdate,-12))
```

of course you would want to consider what to do with products that have only been just introduced (eg a week old) and never sold.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might come close

```
update product 
set price = price * 0.9 
where  pid NOT IN (
   select pr.pid 
   from product pr
   left outer join purchase pu   
   on pu.pid = pr.pid
   where (( pu.date_purchase != null) 
           AND pu.date_purchase < (SYSDATE - 365))
   or pu.pid == null
);
```